# Get the remainder with the % operator

Tags: c++

I’m a beginner to programming & C++.
I’ve recently been learning about the basic arithmetic operators and just got to the end of the chapter, where it was a project exercise.

The exercise:

- You are making a program for a bus service.
  A bus can transport 50 passengers at once.
  Given the number of passengers waiting in the bus station as input, you need to calculate and output how many empty seats the last bus will have.

I tried to solve this exercise for about 2.5 hours, with some breaks, but I could not get it to work. I then decided to look at some solutions other had come up with and the best solution was:

```
int total;
cin >> total;

cout << 50 - total % 50;

return 0;
```

I don’t know if I’m to stupid for programming, but I can’t understand this solution. I read some of the comments about the solution where “the author” tried to explain why this solution was the best but I still couldn’t get it.

When I look at the solution, you’ll first divide the value that is stored inside `total` with 50, and then get the remainder of that - then subtract that with 50. I guess that works if the value inside `total` is above 100? But what if the value was like 60? How are you supposed to get the remainder of 60 / 50?

Once again, I’m new to this and there is obviously something that I miss, but I don’t know what. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If the input was 60 then 60 % 50 == 10, and 50 - 10 = 40 empty seats.

Comment: You are on the right track, look at your code. What do you think the value of "input" is? Has it been assigned a value before that line or not?

Comment: partial people?

Comment: Let’s say that x == 142. You then subtract 50 from x until x is less than 50. (You will subtract 2 times, so 2 busses is filled) Then you’ll have 42 people left, and 8 seats will be unoccupied in the third and last bus, right?

Comment: You inadvertently renamed `total` to `input`. I fixed it for you in your code; you can edit the remaining references yourself. (Also, it helps if you make variable names stand out from the text by including them in back-ticks ` `.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say for example that each bus has 50 seats, and your input is 110. When you divide the input by the max_cap, you will get 2. than, when you multiply the result (2) by max_cap, you will get 100. When you substract the result from the input, you will get 10.

```
int main()
{    
    int input = 110; // the number of passengers waiting in the bus station
    constexpr int max_cap = 50; // a bus can transport 50 passengers at once
    
    int full_buses = input / max_cap;
    int remainder = input - (full_buses * max_cap); // the number of passengers in the last bus

    int free_seats_in_the_last_bus = max_cap - remainder;
}
```

In short, it is the same Modulo Operator (%):

```
int main()
{
    int input = 110; // the number of passengers waiting in the bus station
    constexpr int max_cap = 50; // a bus can transport 50 passengers at once

    int remainder = input % max_cap; // the number of passengers in the last bus

    int free_seats_in_the_last_bus = max_cap - remainder;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How are you supposed to get the remainder of 60 / 50?

Let x be 60. Subtract 50 from x until x is less than 50. The number of subtractions (1) is the result of the division and what remains (10) is the remainder. The division result is the number of full busses, and the remainder is the number of occupied seats in the last bus.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the suggested answer `50 - total % 50` is wrong. It fails when `total` is a multiple of 50; your formula gives 50 as the number of empty seats, when the correct answer is 0.

A solution that works on all (non-negative) inputs is `49 - (total + 49) % 50`. It's a bit more complicated to see what's going on here, but if you try it with various values (including multiples of 50!) you should see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

To better understand modulo you could just subtract. Subtract 50 until you can not subtract 50 or you will get a negative number. And this will be your result.

Example 60%50:
60-50 = 10
It is not possible to subtract 50 from 10 without getting negative so 10 is your result.

Example 100%50:
100-50 = 50
50-50= 0
Its not possible to subtract 50 from 0 without getting negative so your result is 0

Example 40%50:
40-50 is negative so your result is 40